# What's the plural of faulty?

Tags: irregular-plurals

When I have multiple **faulty** items, could I refer to the bunch of them as "**the faulties**"?

**What is the correct plural of faulty (item)?**

*Note: https://word.labstack.com/faulty/plural would suggest "faulties", but I have not found other evidence so far.*

*Note: (like e.g. in German as "die Fehlerhaften")*

Comment: Adjectives can’t be pluralized. Only nouns can. The noun in “the faulty item” is “item”. That word can be pluralize, the word which modifies it (faulty) can’t. You can’t even say the original sentence without the noun.

Comment: German “die Fehlerhaften” could probably be translated as “the faulty ones”, with “one” as a pro-form replacing any contextually retrievable noun.

Comment: Unless you’re referring to Basil’s family (in which case you’ve misspelt his surname), you’re using informal language. I can imagine someone saying, “That’s five faulties and only three goods. I want me money back.” But with informal language, spelling is somewhat flexible.

Comment: If you are nominalising an adjective (which English speakers do all the time), then it takes a regular plural: _faulties_.

Comment: Perhaps 'duds' or 'rejects' would fit.

Comment: One faulty item is a lemon . . .

Answer (score 5):

The English you are suggesting would not be correct Fault has a plural (faults) as it is a noun. Faulty is an adjective which has no plural.

**English does not inflect** **adjectives for case, number or gender agreement** with the nouns they modify. [Inflection Rules](https://www.thoughtco.com/inflection-grammar-term-1691168)
English does inflect nouns and pronouns (for number, not case or gender). However there are some examples of plural nouns which are being used as adjectives and still keeping the plural form. see Note

**The car has one fault. The truck has two faults. They were both faulty when I bought them.**

The car has one fault(**noun**). The truck has two faults(**noun**). They were both faulty (**adjective**) when I bought them.

---

> **fault noun** [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fault)  a broken part or weakness in a machine or system:
>
> The car has a serious design fault.
>
> **faulty adjective** [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/faulty) A faulty machine or device is not perfectly made or does not work correctly:
>
> His arguments were based on faulty reasoning.

---

Note

> **Adjectives in English do not change (agree) with the noun** that they modify: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjective-and-adverb-phrases/adjectives-and-adjective-phrases-typical-errors)
>
> The tropical birds were beautiful. Not: The tropical birds were beautifuls.
>
> **plural nouns often act as adjectives**, as in these examples: [M W Learners Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/can-a-plural-noun-act-as-an-adjective)
>
> Teachers unions
>
> Girls hockey
>
> Nurses station

Comment: Except those should be "Teachers', Girls'" and "Nurses'" and someone has invented a "rule" because they can't be bothered with apostrophes.

Comment: @Andrew Leach a serious question; so who do you think  invented a rule someone at  Merriam-Webster or Cambridge or Richard Nordquist at thought .com. The " they can't be bothered with apostrophes" is  Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Dictionaries merely reflect current usage, whether that's actually correct or not. It can have the effect of perpetuating errors.

Comment: @Andrew Leach, Personally I am a bit of a Luddite so I would have to agree with you on that point, however I feel fairly confident in saying, that I believe many would disagree and say that is how  a language evolves. On the other hand I original came to this site because of a rule I was taught that nowadays nobody remembers or has never heard of, and so they just pronounce it never was a rule.